# How do you avoid bad thoughts whilst praying

Tags: salat, practical-islam

How do you avoid bad thoughts whilst praying

Comment: Salaams and welcome to Islam Stack Exchange. Unlike a typical Internet forum, we expect questions here to be both practical and answerable, and to show focus and research effort. Vague one-liner questions are generally considered low-quality and risk being deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What has helped me is really focusing on what your saying, so when your reciting Quran during salah focus on each word and try understanding it, always pray in a quiet area. In shaa Allah this helps

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tried to find translations of the Ayat recited during Salah so I know exactly what I'm saying instead of trying to figure as many words out as I can but ive yet to find a source that is reliable and has exactly what I'm looking for, would you know of any?

Comment: I have an app that helps, its in English and Arabic. Go to the play store on your phone and type in "Quran in Arabic and English" a blue icon will come up with the letter qah in Arabic, let me know if you found it

Comment: I didn't find the one you were telling me about in particular because I think that one is only found on the play store and I have an iPhone but I found a good one that's perfect having just searched "Quran English" which is really helpful. Thank you again!

Comment: Well that works! Your welcome